Can Oracle ORA_ROWSCN reliably be used to indicate lack of change?
For a row in an Oracle table - if I read the ORA_ROWSCN now and store it then moments (or days) later read the ORA_ROWSCN and it is the same, can I safely know that the row has not changed?
PSUDO CODE:
remote = PK, ORA_ROWSCN FROM Oracle
local = PK, stored_scn FROM local store

new records = remote PK not in local PK
deleted records = local PK not in remote PK
UNchanged records = local PK = remote PK AND local stored_scn = remote ORA_ROWSCN

//any PK not in one of the above MAY have changed since local store was created


Yes, if ORA_ROWSCN has not advanced, there has been no change to the row (or to any of the rows in that block).
ORA_ROWSCN is tracked at the block level by inspecting the 24-byte ITL ("interested transaction list") slots at the start of each block. As there isn't even remotely close to a separate ITL slot for each row (there are typically 3 to a dozen for potentially hundreds of rows in the block), Oracle will report the highest SCN it finds in the ITL slots, which represents a change made to some row(s) in the block but not necessarily to all rows. Therefore an advanced SCN doesn't mean a row has changed, but a non-advanced SCN does mean a row hasn't changed.
If you want more precise information, whereby the SCN is known for certain for each row, you need to enable ROWDEPENDENCIES which will add a 6-byte SCN slot to every row. That increases space consumption, but it allows you to isolate exactly which rows have  changed, and this is leveraged by certain replication technologies.
However, if you are willing to get false positives, checking for a non-advanced SCN to discount the possibility that a row was updated will work just fine without enabling row dependencies.
